# How to remove the divider lines between tabs?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here my layout

[image]

I want to remove the line circled in red , is there a way ?

I have tried manipulating with the images , but it was of no use

I have also used

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

and still then was no expected result .

I am using a custom theme , with stlye as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="Theme.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Sevenbee</item>




</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Sevenbee</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Sevenbee</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_sevenbee</item>  
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_sevenbee</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_sevenbee</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_sevenbee</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_sevenbee</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Sevenbee" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_sevenbee</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Sevenbee.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Sevenbee</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Sevenbee</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change tab divider color same as your tab bg color. so this effect like you not have any divder.

```
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/background</item>
```

Comment: Hey I used it , and I used a transparent png and it value . it fixed the divider issue . But now the tab indicator is gone ,i.e. those green line

Comment: Hey never mind , it got fixed , i made a minor error , thanks for the solution